# replace date with another date but keep the same time PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have a datetime variable which has date and time and I am trying to replace the date with another date (lest say the following day) but keeping the same time.

My datetime variable is as shown in the debugger:

[image]

I want to change the date to 11-04 instead of 11-03 (the following day, adding one day) but will keep the time as it is so the final datatime will be 2017-11-04 07:15:00.000000

Comment: What format is the original datetime variable

Comment: ... also, what format is the `$newdate` variable? Is it a string, an integer timestamp or something else. Please show your code where you assign values to these variables

Comment: sorry, I added the format in my question

Comment: Can you show a real example, that format looks a little odd

Comment: I will debug in my code to get exactly how it looks and will edit my question

Comment: Please **show your code** where you assign values to these variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the original variable is an instance of PHP DateTime class, you can use SetDate method. It changes date, but keeps the time.

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.setdate.php

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime();
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\n";
$date->setDate(2001, 2, 3);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\n";
```

Output:

```
2017-11-02 22:47:34
2001-02-03 22:47:34
```

Comment: The PHP documentation includes number of examples, but point taken - I've updated the answer.

Comment: Except that the OP has attempted to explain he has a date in a string that he wants to use. Not just invent a date and time to output.

Comment: Yes, the question has been updated, so my answer is not relevant anymore. Looks like it's not the date that needs to be changed, but the date *format*

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to set it up with the following day?

Comment: @SMH yes, you can use `$date->modify("+1 day");`. But really, take a look at the DateTime documentaion at http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php - there are number of convenient methods. Description for "modify" is at http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this

Here is one using the DateTime Object

```
<?php
$d = '2017-11-03 15:15:00.000000';

$dt = new DateTime($d);
echo 'Check original date ' . $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u') . PHP_EOL;;
// add 1 day
$dt->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));

echo 'New date ' . $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u');
```

RESULT:

```
Check original date 2017-11-03 15:15:00.000000
New date 2017-11-04 15:15:00.000000
```

Comment: thanks but I need to keep the time but just change the date

Comment: Ok, I added the time back into the `date()` formatting

Comment: @RiggsFolly if I had to guess, OP has two *date-like* strings (the first of which is probably in ISO 8601 format). They want to take the time portion from the first and set it to the date of the second

Comment: @Phil Yea that sounds likely. I will see what OP says about this second attempt

Comment: I have updated the question with data from the debugger, is it clear now? Thank you